# IIS 8.5 SQL Error Locating Server 26 During Deployment

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sensenet

When trying to deploy a project to a website using IIS on my local machine I am getting a SQL Network Interfaces Error 26 (detailed error below).

Attempting deployment of [sensenet](http://www.sensenet.com/) from zip file as instructed in their [guide](http://wiki.sensenet.com/index.php?title=How_to_install_Sense/Net_from_source_package_(IIS_7.5_and_IIS_7.0)).

I've been trouble shooting using the online suggestions found on MSDN, Stack and Code Project but nothing works as of yet.

I've disabled both Windows Firewall and my third party one as well. The port I am using is 8081 (8080 is taken by a working website on my IIS), I have also checked that the SQL services are running. TCP/IP is also enabled as per [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672(v=sql.110).aspx) method.

I am trying to create a new DB with the scripts in the installation zip provided by SenseNet.

I am using IIS 8.5, web deploy 5 and SQL management studio 2012.

Does any one have any other suggestions as to what could be causing this error?

Thanks

**Summary**

> The database 'SNCR' could not be created.
>       A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
>       Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

---

> Warning: The database 'SNCR' could not be created.
>       Retrying operation 'Add' on object dbFullSql (server=".C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL";database=SNCR;uid=sa). Attempt 1 of 5.

**Detailed**

```
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentClientServerException: The database 'SNCR' could not be created. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlServerDatabaseProvider.AddHelper(DeploymentObject source)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.Add(DeploymentObject source, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAdd(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleUpdate(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.UI.InstallProgressWizardPage.OnWorkerDoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

Comment: Have you set TCP/IP protocol to access on Sql Server?

Comment: @JoeTaras Just reconfirmed and yes it's enabled and giving the same error.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL` cannot possibly be a valid SQL Server.  The name must be `hostname` or `hostname\instancename`. What you provide there looks like some sort of folder name.

Comment: And don't use `sa` in an app. Ever.

Answer (score 3):

Check the web.config file: look for the SQL connection string and see what user name and password was added there during the install process (it should not be the 'sa' user but a custom account like 'sensenet6'). This user should have access to the database that is also added to the connection string. Here's a forum topic that might be helpful: http://forum.sensenet.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7279&p=10803&hilit=404&sid=c79596c733ccd9b721